# How can this scenario cause an UpdateException in EntityFramework while calling SaveChanges?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4

I am unable to understand the line in bold from this msdn page:-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738618.aspx

SaveChanges can generate an UpdateException when an object added to the ObjectContext cannot be successfully created in the data source. **This can happen if a row with the foreign key specified by the relationship already exists.** When this occurs, you cannot use Refresh to update the added object in the object context. Instead, reload the object with a value of OverwriteChanges for MergeOption.

In a table, a foreign key column can have a single value multiple times. e.g. DepartmentID foreign key in Users Table: More than one User can have same DepartmentID foreign key.

So how can this cause an UpdateException ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy. You have an entity in your context in the `Added` state with a PK value of something already in the DB. This is common when people try to use stub objects incorrectly. If you want more help than that, you need to isolate your problem and post your code.

Comment: I don't have any code, I was just studying the EntityFramework. You are right that if we have a row in our context with `Added` state, it will not be created in data source and an exception will occur. But here it is written that "if a row with the foreign key already exists". Means we are adding a UserTable row with a DeptId foreign key to the ObjectContext, where a row with this same DeptId foreign key already exists in the DataSource. So this should not cause an exception.

Comment: The scenario you give should indeed not cause this error. So the problem is probably not exactly this. Trace the SQL and look at the `InnerException` if present.